# google cloud Forwarding rules is very slow

Tags: networking, tcp, google-compute-engine

new to setting up a load balancer:
I am working with the google compute engine.

1. Set up 3 servers running on 3 different ports: 5010, 5011 and 5012.
2. `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5010/11/12..` on each specific server
3. set up a health check to port 8080 . let's call it `example-health-check`
4. set up a target pool that contains the health check and **all the 3 instances**. let's call it `example-target-pool`
5. Set up a `forwarding rule` with `tcp:5010-5012` and linked it target pool to the `example-target-pool`

when I go to the lb ip in each one of the ports the connection is very weird. it works but very slow in most of the requests but once in a while a request is very fast to pass..

any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have all your servers listening on ports 5010-5012 or its server1 listening on 5010, server2 on 5011 and so on ? If its later than the connection you are getting is expected. The reason behind is that forward rule receives incofming traffic and forwards in to the healthy instances. It doesn't do any check to see which server is serving traffic on what port. As such, if the incoming traffic for a specific port goes to a different server which is not configured for that port the traffic will be dropped.